# flutter run --no-build does not work together with --release

Tags: flutter

I run `flutter build ios` and then subsequently `flutter run --release --no-build`.
As far as I understand, the second statement should *only run* and not **rebuild** the executable, but it's always rebuilding as well. Am I missing something?

**Update:** When I run `flutter run --no-build`, it first builds the executable and then says `Could not find the built application bundle at build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app. Error launching application on <my iPhone>.` This makes sense because there is no `Runner.app` but only a `<application name>.app` in that directory.

I can workaround by running **`flutter run --use-application-binary`**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running `flutter run --no-build --release`, `--no-build` *clashes* with `--release`.

#### `flutter run -h`

Here are the applicable sections of the help command (highlighting is mine):

> `--[no-]build`                                      If necessary, build the app before running.
>
> `--release`                                         **Build** a release version of your app.

Apparently, `--release` will **always** cause a *rebuild*. If you omit it, you will see that the debug build does not recompile before running a second time.

---

This means that it is not possible (at least not like this) to run a *release* build without compiling. You could potentially [file an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new/choose) about it.

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunately, it doesn't work with `--debug` either, it triggers a rebuild as well.

Comment: @rgisi `--no-build` works for me without other flags. You will probably want to file an issue - I am not sure someone here can help you with that.